# ConcurrentSkipListMap how to use it properly

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, concurrentskiplistmap

I am using ConcurrentSkipListMap in my code and I want to ensure a method to be concurrent-safe.

```
    public synchronized UserLogin getOrCreateLogin(Integer userId) {
        // new user
        if (!sessionCache.containsKey(userId)) {
            String sessionKey = sessionKeyPool.getKey();
            sessionCache.putIfAbsent(userId, sessionKey);
            return userSessions.computeIfAbsent(sessionKey, userLogin -> new UserLogin(userId, sessionKey));
        } else { // old user, check session
            String oldSessionKey = sessionCache.get(userId);
            UserLogin old = userSessions.get(oldSessionKey);
            if (!old.isExpired()) return old;
            log.info("Session expired! Create another. User id: " + userId + ", last login: " + old.getStartTime());
            String newKey = sessionKeyPool.getKey();
            UserLogin another = new UserLogin(userId, newKey);
            userSessions.replace(newKey, another);
            sessionCache.replace(userId, newKey);
            return another;
        }
    }
```

I know that the map atomatically does `containsKey()`, `get` and so one. But does not mean the whole block cannot be accessed by two threads at the same time, but at least between line and line the happen-before relationship is guarded(the first thread reaches this line will exit this line first). But, then how to actually **use** these methods to have a *composable* and consistent result? How do I lock these lines?

How can I lock to gain the finest granularity without compromising the consistency of output data?

Comment: why would you _analyze_ (besides interest) JDK _core_ classes, especially the ones that have to do with concurrency - which there are very, very few people to fully understand them? I don't understand the overall question you have

Comment: With the chunk of code that you have provided is hard to tell, but do you think that locking on the userID would be enough ?

Comment: I want to understand them, if possible. And I think there are ppl out there do. I just simply ask a question. If it violates any rules or being too broad, I agree it can be closed, which I don't see. Or if you want to, I can put it like "how atomicity is achieved by this method?" without mention it is from JDK. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @dreamcrash Yes I think so, but I struggle to properly put it into code due to my limited exp at this field.

Comment: Indeed, it would be nice to know how that doGet ensures atomicity.

Comment: You can’t compose atomic operations, that’s a contradiction in itself. Instead, get rid of obsolete pre-test methods and start with the designated atomic operations. E.g. instead of doing `sessionCache.containsKey(userId)`, followed by `sessionCache.putIfAbsent(userId, sessionKey)`, you can do the `putIfAbsent` in the first place and check the return value. That’s what it is for. But you are making your life unnecessarily hard by maintaining two maps. What’s the purpose of the string indirection? Why don’t you just map from `userId` to `UserLogin`?

Comment: The two maps are for distinct purposes. Because when he logins for the 1st time, he provides the id to server, and backend generates an unique session key for him, which expires in 10 min, and subsequent calls only provides session key, not id. So, to find if an user is new or old, and whether his sessionKey expires or not in calls other than login, I have to find by id in `sessionCache`; or, I have to iterate `userSessions` to find session key and check. (but.. is it slower to search among `valueSet()`? I thought so because repetition can happen)

Comment: Another question, when I check the return value is null or not, can threads intersect with each other? I mean, the line of `putIfAbsent` is guarded, but if I do: `String returned = sessionCache.putIfAbsent(userId, sessionKey); if (returned == null) {...}` I suppose the `if` call is not safe right?

Comment: When multiple threads invoke `putIfAbsent` on a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` with the same key, at most one thread can return with `null`, as all other threads will get the value put by that “winner” thread. So the block of the subsequent `if(returned == null) {…}` can only be executed by a single thread. Whether this is sufficient depends on your application logic. As said, the two maps are an unnecessary complication. There’s still a one-to-one relation between `userId` and `UserLogin`. Therefore, you still can have one map mapping to both, the `sessionKey` and the  `UserLogin`.

Comment: I understand your point of one-to-one in the logic. So when a new user id comes in, I need to iterate this only map `values()` to check if it exists or not? If it is a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` would it be slower to iterate? Would building two maps make this check faster?